# How can I order age classes (character) values?

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataset (dataframe) with age population classes in a column:

```
[1] "Toddlers"       "Other children" "Adolescents"    "Adults"         "Elderly"       
[6] "Very elderly"   "Infants"
```

I need to order the groups by age. Obviously R does not know which ranges of years are behind the groups. 
Therefore I define the following order:

```
"Infants" = 0 years,
"Toddlers" = 1-2 years,
"Other children" = 3-9 years,
"Adolescents" = 10-17 years,
"Adults" = 18-64 years,
"Elderly" = 65-74 years,
```

The dataset is downloaded from https://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/microstrategy/foodex2-level-1.
How can I order my data as described by the above defined sequence? How can I tell R to apply my definition?

Comment: use this one https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_relevel.html

Comment: thanks but this is abit hard, because the dataset consists of several hundred items:  "Toddlers"       "Other children" "Adolescents"    "Adults"         "Elderly"       
"Very elderly"   "Infants" in the dataset. So I cannot define the whole sequence in this column

Comment: understood. can u add `dput` of your data frame?

Comment: I found a solution for visualisation: I use the ggbarplot funtion and added ```order = c("Infants", "Toddlers", "Other children","Adolescents","Adults", "Elderly", "Very elderly" )```

Comment: There are hundreds of age groups?